# In LaTeX how to intentionally place a word to the right border of the last line of a paragraph?

Tags: latex

For example, I have a paragraph like this:

```
a bb ccc cc cc d |

dddd eee ff
```

Now I want to add a word END to the right border of the last line, so that it looks like this:

```
a bb ccc cc cc d |

dddd eee ff______|END
```

The underscores are something to the effect of \hfill to fill the horizontal space, and the word END is placed **after** the right border of the paragraph (so \hfill itself is not enough).

Sometimes when an unbreakable word in a line is too long, LaTeX cannot split the line and some letters will appear outside the right border.  That's usually not good-looking.  However, now I intentionally want to achieve this effect.

Note that I am not asking about margin note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a zero-width box in which the text is left-aligned. This is a working example (using the lipsum package to get some dummy text):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\hfill\rlap{\hspace*{1em}END}
\end{document}
```

You may want to adjust or leave out the `\hspace*{1em}` depending on how close you want the END to be to the right text margin.

Comment: Using `\rlap{\hspace*{1em}END}` looks a bit cleaner.